# What is better - use ajax calls from assets/javascript/*.js or *.js.erb views?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, erb

I'm writing an admin service from network communicator using rails.

So my problem:
User clicks a button -> groups user sees network groups -> user chooses some group -> user sees IP addresses. I have two forms on the page and I need to send data to the page two times without the page reloading.

The first server response is a list of network group names.

The second server response is a list of IP addresses in one of the groups.

Question:

Which is better to do after user request:

1. JS.ERB way

   Get data, put it into views/some_file.js.erb, write something like "respond_to{ |format| format.js }" in controller. Expected result: browser recieve js, js code run on client, js code append data into table on page.
2. JS with ajax in assets/javascript way

   Send data in json format to client. js code make ajax call to server, bowser recieve json-data form server, js append data into table on page.

Please, explain the advantages and disadvantages of both ways. Thanks.

Comment: `a_file.js.erb` is rendered via an Engine to generated HTML. It also expects ruby code, so it is "listening" while rendering the .js.erb. JSON is not really rendered, is it a bunch of values that are not rendered into HTML but just string, which makes it faster than rendered html. But JSON implies an heavy client-side support to parse & display the received data.

Comment: Using a client side framework would make the client heavier but greatly reduces callback-hell and helps organize the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the best way to do this would be to make an AJAX request to another controller action like `groups#names` in your `groups_controller.rb` and have that action render JSON.

do this in a javascript asset such as `app/assets/javascripts/script.js` like so:

```
$('#get-group-names-button').live('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "/groups/names",
    type: 'post',
    data: {'groupId': 'whatever'}
  });
});
```

Then in the groups_controller

```
def names
  if group_names
    render :json => group_names, :status => 200
  else
    render :status => 400
  end
end
```

Then parse that JSON response using jquery `done()` on the client and append the data with whatever HTML formatting you need in javascript.

This can be greatly aided by using a client-side framework like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), and a templating language like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Here is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery) on the topic produced by [Ryan Bates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148722/ryanb)